# Is MS-CHAPv2 incompatible with securely stored passwords?

Tags: passwords, authentication, wireless, bcrypt, peap

I have a directory service that can speak a number of protocols and is used for user authentication. Currently user credentials are stored using Bcrypt to protect them in case of a compromised database.

Unfortunately there are a number of services that I would like to point at this server that only support MS-CHAPv2 for authentication (specifically wireless equipment). MS-CHAPv2 doesn't send the password to the authentication server, instead it applies MD4 to the password to derive an encryption key and then uses that to DES encrypt a challenge hash consisting of a random values chosen by both the client and server and the user's password.

My initial feeling is in order to support MS-CHAPv2 I would have to store either the user's password in plaintext or the MD4 of the user's password. Neither of these are acceptable to me.

Is there a way to store user's passwords securely and still be able to support MS-CHAPv2?

Comment: Is this a custom service or a commercial/off the shelf solution you're trying to use? If its COTS whats the product name?

Comment: It is not a COTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

As a challenge-response protocol, MS-CHAP2 restricts how you can store the password server-side. And it is somewhat weaker than bcrypt.

You could provide a configuration option like: Support MS-CHAP2? (warning: enabling this stores passwords insecurely)